# Does anyone know good "Hello, world" SOA (service oriented architecture) coding examples?

Tags: soa

I am interested in learning more about SOA. Most of the explanations I see have little code and a lot of chatter, philosophy and rambling. I am a kind of person that learns best when I have code to look at (it does not have to be perfect or 100% right, just a good example). Does anyone know of good and simple coding examples of SOA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SOA is an architecture (not a framework), you can't simply code entier SOA. It involves lot of factors, that is why you see lot of chatter, but I know the confusion you are having (which is same for people with coding background).

Real SOA implementation involves lot of co-ordination, integration and maintenance than coding. Coding will be small part, which is writing services. If you can write any webservice, then you learned required coding for SOA. So, read about **Web Services** (REST WS and JAX-WS (assuming java background) etc.,) using any programming language.

Once you are done with **service** writing, it will be **integrators** part, which also involves little bit coding (lot of integration tools are there by Oracle and other vendros), so little coding here.

Only these two layers really involve coding part in SOA.

In a nutshell, come out from programmer perspective, if you want to enter SOA world. Programming is small part in SOA world.

Comment: @thinkisteep: Nice answer. Pardon me if I am still coming at it from a code-first-theory-later perspective. Let's say I have a N-tier application. If I expose some of the business logic as web services; then that is SOA?

Comment: No, it is not SOA. It means you just have few services available. In SOA, you will orchestrate/integrate (arrange/weave together) those services to accomplish certain business task. Then, you will maintain and govern them.

Comment: So, I expose those supporting-services and the "business task" + secret sauce (code not exposed) and that is SOA?

Comment: No, it means that SOA is meaningless in the context of one application. Dont think as a programmer doing 1 application, but as project manager trying to integrate many systems in a company, say a bank. Then SOA is for you.

Comment: **"Once you are done with service writing, it will be integrators part"**, can you kindly explain how can integration be done? and are there any frameworks to do so?